# fill a heart in red with geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot:

```
h <- 
  data_frame(t = seq(0, (2 * pi), by = 0.005), 
             x = 13 * sin(t)^3, 
             y = 13 * cos(t) - 
               5 * cos(2 * t) - 
               2 * cos(3 * t) - 
               1 * cos(4 * t),
             chunk = floor(x)) %>%
  select(-t) 


ggplot(data = h, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_path(color = "maroon")+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

How can I fill it in red ?
I do not know how to do it with geom_path.

Comment: Use  `geom_polygon(color = "maroon", fill = "red")+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_path` does not have a `fill` aesthetic, because it is used to create a path, not closed shapes. Use `geom_polygon` instead:

```r
ggplot(data = h, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = "red") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: It is a duplicate.